# How do you order a tournaments games by the name of each games field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games, inverse_of: :tournament, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :games, allow_destroy: true
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tournament
  belongs_to :field, optional: true
end

class Field < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I would like to order the games based on the name of the field that the game is played on, but in the games I only have access to `field_id`, not `field.name`.

`t.games.order('field.name')` and `t.games.order('fields.name')` don't work. They give a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "fields")` error.

Comment: `Game.left_joins(:fields).order('fields.name')` you might need to add GROUP BY on some dbs.

Comment: @max `t.games.left_joins(:field).order('fields.name')` worked for me — thanks! Want to make your comment an answer?

Comment: Feel free to answer it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tournament.games.left_joins(:field).order('fields.name')` does the trick.